# how to pass data between fragments from recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two `fragments` and the first fragment has a `recyclerview adapter` were i want to pass adapter position to another fragment on `clicking` the `recycler view`..

**Fragment 1** code from `recyclerview adapter`:

```
holder.address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.i("Position of items...///", String.valueOf(position));
                            //For sending data between fragments

                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putInt("Position", position);
                            StoreDetails storeDetails = new StoreDetails();
                            storeDetails.setArguments(bundle);
                            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                                    .beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new StoreDetails())
                                    .commit();

                        }
                    });
```

**Fragment 2 code:**

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
    if(b != null)
    {
        b.getInt("Position");
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oops sorry..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception from the second fragment..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you are adding `Bundle` in `StoreDetails` `Fragment` and your are passing new object of `StoreDetails` `Fragment`
>
> you need to pass same object of your  `StoreDetails` `Fragment` in which you add the `Bundle` so change this as below code

use this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Position", position);
StoreDetails storeDetails = new StoreDetails();
storeDetails.setArguments(bundle);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
              .beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.content_frame,  storeDetails)
              .commit();
```

instead of this

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
             .beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.content_frame,new StoreDetails())
             .commit();
```

Comment: perfectly notice!

Comment: Yeah i got it.. Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    private Bundle bundle;

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     this.bundle = getArguments();
     if (bundle != null) {
         bundle.getInt("Position");
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oops sorry..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. I got it done from @Nilesh Rathod answer.